# How to run Vertx API Async?

Tags: multithreading, api, asynchronous, vert.x

I try to write Web API with Vertx to serves large users.

```
@Override
public Router router(Vertx vertx) {
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/").handler(this::productionF);
return router;
}

private void productionF(RoutingContext routingContext) {
  // check input
  // read data from redis
  // response
}
```

But now, I want to move this API to Async process to get high performance. I try to use EventBus, but it not work.

Does anyone have any idea or experiment about this?

Comment: Your handler is already async. Second, please post the actual code that doesn't work, not the one that's working.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my boss wants to make it high performance when it processes a large request. He suggests use Thread, runnable and Future, but now I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Without code that's not working, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/51NcLzeY, this is my code. Fail when i run test

Comment: I went over your code, but there's no mention of `eventBus` there. What also bothers me is that you use `executeBlocking` for no reason.